# Flutter Blue set descriptor

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

hi i'm trying to write on a descriptor so that it enables notifications but i can't find the way, the code in java would be this but i can't find a way to translate it to flutter,
any idea?
Im trying to use Flutter Blue Package

```
private void setDescriptor() {
   BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptors().get(0);
   descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);       
   mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
}
```

Comment: On the [readme page](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue), the instruction are clear. The basic are the same. You list available characteristic, then list available descriptor of each characteristic, then you can write to it. Also, if you want to enabling notification value of its charatceristic, there is `characteristic.setNotifyValue = true` method, then you can listen to it.

Comment: Ok but in java i can set descriptor with BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE, how i can do that in flutter?